# Time complexity of log

Tags: time-complexity, runtime

I was studying for runtime analysis.

One of the question that I encountered is this.

Which function would grow the slowest?

1. n^0.5
2. log(n^0.5)
3. (log(n))^0.5
4. log(n) * log(n)

I thought the answer was 2 after I draw the graph.

However, the answer is 3. I am not sure why this is the answer.

Could someone explain why this is the case?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

2.log(n^0.5)=0.5log(n)=log(n)

3.(log(n))^0.5= sqrt(log(n)) which is smaller in magnitude than 2.

Comment: I think I understood now, but I would like to confirm it. log(n) > sqrt(log(n)) thus, (log(n))^0.5 is slower than just log(n) (which is log(n)^0.5 but then 0.5 will be removed since it is a constant. right? Thank you!

Comment: O(log(n)) == O(0.5(log(n))), yes you can drop constants.

Answer (score 0):

I have explained in very layman terms in the picture below with a little mathematics.

[image]

Tell me if you still have confusion.

PS: Both are log so I don't think we worry about time complexity of such functions in this modern age.

Comment: This is a very mathematical approach to solving it. I think I might need some time to digest it. Thank you!